# Wildfly ignores included library

Tags: java, maven, wildfly

I have all libraries in the WEB-INF/lib folder, however at execution time, 
Wildfly is complaining about a missing method:

```
2018-08-13 09:56:14,723 ERROR [stderr] (Thread-174) Exception in thread "Thread-174" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.collect.Sets$SetView.iterator()Lcom/google/common/collect/UnmodifiableIterator;
2018-08-13 09:56:14,723 ERROR [stderr] (Thread-174)     at org.reflections.Reflections.expandSuperTypes(Reflections.java:380)
2018-08-13 09:56:14,724 ERROR [stderr] (Thread-174)     at org.reflections.Reflections.<init>(Reflections.java:126)
2018-08-13 09:56:14,724 ERROR [stderr] (Thread-174)     at org.nd4j.linalg.api.ops.factory.DefaultOpFactory.<init>(DefaultOpFactory.java:71)
2018-08-13 09:56:14,724 ERROR [stderr] (Thread-174)     at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
2018-08-13 09:56:14,724 ERROR [stderr] (Thread-174)     at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
2018-08-13 09:56:14,724 ERROR [stderr] (Thread-174)     at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
2018-08-13 09:56:14,724 ERROR [stderr] (Thread-174)     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
2018-08-13 09:56:14,724 ERROR [stderr] (Thread-174)     at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:442)
2018-08-13 09:56:14,724 ERROR [stderr] (Thread-174)     at org.nd4j.linalg.factory.Nd4j.initWithBackend(Nd4j.java:6192)
2018-08-13 09:56:14,724 ERROR [stderr] (Thread-174)     at org.nd4j.linalg.factory.Nd4j.initContext(Nd4j.java:6087)
2018-08-13 09:56:14,725 ERROR [stderr] (Thread-174)     at org.nd4j.linalg.factory.Nd4j.<clinit>(Nd4j.java:201)
```

I checked the class-path entries at runtime and it turns out, that Guava 20.0.0 is missing. However, the Guava library is included in the lib-folder and also specified as Maven dependency.

Is there any special handling for libraries I am not aware? Thanks!

Comment: Can we see the relevant parts of your pom.xml?  If it is a dependency and your `packaging` in the pom.xml is `war` it should be included.

Comment: @stdunbar thanks for your response. as I said, the Guava-jar file is existing in the WEB-INF/lib folder, but is not loaded into the classpath by Wildfly when starting the deployment.

Comment: You have multiple versions of Guava on your classpath. The duplicate JAR comes from Weld itself. you'll need to downgrade to same version in your Weld distribution and mark it as provided (don't bundle it) or exclude it https://developer.jboss.org/thread/196551

Answer (score 0):

You have to include a special JBoss file ("jboss-deployment-structure.xml") in your WEB-INF folder, listing all the modules (that are part of the default JEE stack of Wildfly) you want to ignore, so that the guava jar in your webapp has the priority over the one of WF (%JBOSS_HOME/modules/system/layers/base/com/google/guava/main)

Example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jboss-deployment-structure xmlns="urn:jboss:deployment-structure:1.2">
    <deployment>
        <exclusions>                
            <module name="com.google.guava"/>           
        </exclusions>   
    </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

Comment: If WildFly makes Guava visible to deployments by default then that sounds like a bug to me.

Comment: Thanks, I already tried that, but the Guava-dependency is still missing at runtime. Strangely enough, I set up a second Wildfly (exactly same Wildfly version and Java version) - here it is working fine (with and without the jboss-deployment-structure.xml-file - obviously it does not matter??)

Comment: @Pii did you found the root cause ? I am struggling with the same thing.  It works when I deploy it in "local" but not on my server although the war is strictly the same. Is there an environment variable to change ?

Answer (score 0):

Read this answer if you're using WL.

I had a similar issue on my web application deployed on weblogic.

There's a conflict between your library and a standard library already present on your application server.

Add this weblogic.xml on WEB-INF folder:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<wls:weblogic-web-app xmlns:wls="http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app/1.4/weblogic-web-app.xsd">
        <wls:weblogic-version><my_wl_version</wls:weblogic-version>
        <wls:context-root>my_app</wls:context-root>
        <wls:container-descriptor>
            <wls:prefer-application-packages>
                <wls:package-name>com.google.*</wls:package-name>
            </wls:prefer-application-packages>
        </wls:container-descriptor>
    </wls:weblogic-web-app>
```

Comment: What do you mean by *WL*?

Comment: @Pii i mean WebLogic